# GCC 7.1 on RHEL 6 64 bit compiles Fortran as 32 bit

Tags: gcc, fortran, 32bit-64bit, gfortran

I have managed to compile GCC 7.1 on RHEL 6 64 bit with `configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-7.1`. Unfortunately, compiling with `gfortran` produces 32 bit binaries by default.

How can I tell `gfortran` always to compile as 64 bit and use `/opt/gcc-7.1/lib64` in  `RPATH` by default?

Suprisingly, the system-bundled `gfortran` does 64 bit by default.

Comment: That should not happen. Consider adding tag [tag:fortran], eventhough you are not asking about the language, to get more attention.

Comment: @VladimirF Yep, something seems fishy about it. I did `--disable-multilib` and I had 64 bit only, but this seems more than a hack than a solution.